# JQuery nonresponsive click function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am building a Chrome extension. I have a simple html file (containing just a div, an image and an empty table). I then echo some table rows and data that I read from a database, I got rid of some details since that works. I send an ajax request to retrieve the echo-ed table rows and data and append them to a table in that before mentioned html file.

This is how the php file looks, replacing data with 'something'

```
//a few of these:
echo 
"<tr> 
<td> Something </td>         
<td> Something </td> 
<td> Something </td>
</tr>";
```

I then have a jquery script that handles the appending of the table's contents into the table and is also supposed to handle any table row clicks. It sends that ajax request and appends the table data just fine. This is what that script file looks like

```
$(document).ready(function() {

                    $.urlParam = function(name){
                    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
                    if (results==null){
                       return null;
                    }
                    else{
                       return results[1] || 0;
                    }
                }

                $usern = $.urlParam('user');
                var div = document.getElementById('welcome');
                div.innerHTML = "Pozdravljeni, <a href='https://www.google.si' id='imeUser'><span>" + $usern + "</span></a>! <a href='dodajGeslo.html'><span id='dodajGeslo'> Dodaj Geslo </span></a>";
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://passvault.000webhostapp.com/qryGesla.php',
                    data: {user:$usern},
                    type: "GET",
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#gesla").append(data);
                        $("#load").css("display", "none");
                    }
                });

                $('tr').click( function() {
                    alert('test');
                });

});
```

As you can see on the bottom of the page I have a click function for every tr, that only alerts, and yet when I click on the rows it doesn't work. Can someone help me out, I'm not sure what I'm getting wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use delegated events. The click handler will only be activated on `<tr>`s that existed when the page was loaded. The code which adds the event handlers runs before you populate your table (which it looks like you're doing via ajax).

You need to set the event on an element which already exists when the page loads, but then tell it to delegate the event down to any child elements (of your choosing) which exist when the event fires. I'm going to assume the "gesla" element meets this need, since you're appending the data to it, but if not, choose another parent element higher up the DOM which does (you can just use `document` if nothing else is applicable, but for performance, you should choose the nearest available parent).

```
$("#gesla").on("click", "tr", function() {
  alert("test");
});
```

For more info see here: http://api.jquery.com/on/ (the section entitled "Direct and delegated events").

Comment: Thanks for providing the solution and also the documentation (: I managed to get it working